# iPhonePicker-like-Countdown Plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am looking for a counter looks like the one in [iphonepicker.com](http://iphonepicker.com/demo.php) in jQuery. I was thinking to use the one from iphonepicker.com but it is written using Prototype lib and I need jQuery version.

Here is [the sample image taken from here](http://iphonepicker.com/demo.php):

[image: iphone picker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one written in jQuery: http://opensource.binofo.com/en/opensource/spinthewheel/

It doesn't look quite as nice, but you might be able to modify the CSS to make it look a little more like the one in the OP.

Comment: That site is giving a PHP error.  No luck trying to pull up the Google cached version either, I'm afraid.